# 413 Request Entity Too Large on DigitalOcean

Tags: file, upload, http-status-code-413

I have changed client_max_body_size to 100M on etc/nginx/nginx.conf, I have changed upload_max_filesize to 100M on etc/php5/fpm/php.ini and post_max_size to 100M on etc/php5/fpm/php.ini and I still cannot get the file upload to work.

Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Comment: Did you restart php-fpm and nginx?

Comment: Yep! I made sure of it.

Comment: Which file-related values is phpinfo() echoing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I added those changes, I did in fact restart nginx and php5-fpm. So make sure you do that, but also the changes didn't fully work until I had restarted my server. When I restarted my server, the file upload then worked. Hope that helps anyone in my situation.